# Ansible play runs on one group of hosts, but depends on facts from others

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Here's the basic use case:

I have an NGINX reverse proxy I want to set up and so I specific a play that only runs on the "nginx" group.

However, in order to know the ips to reverse proxy to I need to gather facts from the "upstreams" group. This doesn't happen since the play does not run `setup` on the "upstreams".

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127514/using-facts-from-one-host-group-to-configure-another-host-group-with-ansible) contains a solution I've used before, but I'd like to be able to have it all self contained in a single hosts play that I can run independently of others.

Comment: How do you run a play independently of others?

Comment: @techraf there are many ways, such as  `--start-at-task=START_AT_TASK` and  `--tags`. Or if I limit execution to certain hosts. (I actually think those plays do run, but it just doesn't execute any tasks if you use start-at or tags.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Delegated Facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts), `pre_tasks`, and delegate the facts to the hosts they belong to.

```
- hosts: nginx
  become: yes
  tags:
    - nginx
  vars:
    listen_address: "x.x.x.x"
  pre_tasks:
    - name: 'gather upstream facts.'
      setup:
      delegate_to: "{{item}}"
      delegate_facts: True
      with_items: "{{groups['upstreams']}}"
  roles:
    - role: nginx
      upstreams: "{{ groups['upstreams'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses']) | ipaddr('x.x.x.x') | first | list }}"
```